# How can I do nested loops in powershell for teams

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I'm new to PowerShell and I want to use it to automate different FOR loops in teams.

I made a script that reads information from a file and performs the actions based on this file

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\\Users\\Arik\\Desktop\\names.csv" | foreach{Add-TeamChannelUser -GroupId 7a0d2b07-3e4d-45c5-b455-5622fa5b0b24 -DisplayName "4  -  Execution" -user $\_.email}
```

This script adds user to a certain team and a certain channel. What I want to do is automate the GroupID and the DisplayName process. Is there anyway I can do this? I figured I'd have to use a for loop but I'm not sure how to implement this on PowerShell. I want it to first choose the Team by using the group ID then for each team I want it to look for certain channels and for each channel I want it to add the list of emails. Any help would be appreciate, I'm trying to avoid stack overflow as much as possible.

Comment: im sorry but, can you rephrase what you want done. Im just really confused trying to read this

Comment: The question, as currently written, reads like a request for a "Getting started with PowerShell for Teams" tutorial, so I voted to close it. Check out (and play around with!) `Get-Team` and `Get-TeamChannel` if you want to browse for options, feel free to come back and ask questions about _specific problems_ you're trying to solve when you run into them :-)

Comment: What is $ backslash underscore supposed to mean?

Comment: @Arik Denmark, Any updates?  Are you still facing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've not used powershell for teams, but perhaps try:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\\Users\\Arik\\Desktop\\names.csv"
foreach($user in $users){
    Add-TeamChannelUser -GroupId '7a0d2b07-3e4d-45c5-b455-5622fa5b0b24' -DisplayName "4  -  Execution" -user $user.email
}
```